# Sfinae Templated Implicit Conversion Operator Overloads

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am trying to template a few conversion operator functions to accept various arithmetic types, namely signed / unsigned integer / floating point types, so there are 4 different function template definitions, a couple of which I have included.

```
template<typename UnsignedInteger>
operator std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_integral_v<UnsignedInteger> &&
            !std::is_signed_v<UnsignedInteger>,
            UnsignedInteger
> (){...}

template<typename SignedInteger>
std::enable_if_t<
            is_signed == true ||
            std::is_integral_v<SignedInteger> &&
            std::is_signed_v<SignedInteger>,
            SignedInteger
>operator (){...}
```

Their usage may look something like:

```
fixed<32, 1024> fixed = 32; // implicit constructor invoked, definition not included
uint64_t someFloat = fixed; // conversion invoked
```

I get the fairly generic error `note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'UnsignedInteger'` for this conversion, when I try to use implicit conversions.The conversion operator is created correctly when I remove the enable_if constraint, although only if on conversion function is present / implemented, naturally.

I only have access to c++ 17.

Thanks!

Comment: But isn't `32.5` a double? You don't have a conversion operator to double.

Comment: I've edited my post to avoid confusion but we can assume that the fixed class may be converted to any signed / unsigned integer or floating point value. @康桓瑋

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, packaging template parameter into `std::enable_if` makes it [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), template argument can't be deduced.

You can move the condition to template parameter declaration. E.g.

```
template<typename UnsignedInteger, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<UnsignedInteger> && !std::is_signed_v<UnsignedInteger>, void>* = nullptr>
operator UnsignedInteger (){ ... }

template<typename SignedInteger, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<SignedInteger> && std::is_signed_v<SignedInteger>, void>* = nullptr>
operator SignedInteger (){ ... }
```

[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/GMPcYsc55)